# How To Mount USB External Storage Drive on to ESXi 5.5 Host for VM backup

Tags: vmware-esxi, usb

How To Mount USD External Storage Drive on to ESXi 5.5 Host for VM backup?

After USB Drive plugin, "esxcli storage core device list" shows there is a usb drive attached. But unable to access it.

```
esxcli storage core device list
mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   Display Name: Local USB Direct-Access (mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0)
   Has Settable Display Name: false
   Size: 1907729
   Device Type: Direct-Access 
   Multipath Plugin: NMP
   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   Vendor: Seagate 
   Model: BUP Slim BL     
   Revision: 0108
   SCSI Level: 2
   Is Pseudo: false
   Status: on
   Is RDM Capable: false
   Is Local: true
   Is Removable: true
   Is SSD: false
   Is Offline: false
   Is Perennially Reserved: false
   Queue Full Sample Size: 0
   Queue Full Threshold: 0
   Thin Provisioning Status: unknown
   Attached Filters: 
   VAAI Status: unsupported
   Other UIDs: vml.0000000000766d68626133383a303a30
   Is Local SAS Device: false
   Is USB: true
   Is Boot USB Device: false
   No of outstanding IOs with competing worlds: 32
```

Note: I stopped usbarbitrator.

```
/etc/init.d/usbarbitrator status
usbarbitrator is not running
```

Comment: "esxcli storage core path list -d mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0"

usb.vmhba38-usb.0:0-mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0 UID: usb.vmhba38-usb.0:0-mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0 Runtime Name: vmhba38:C0:T0:L0 Device: mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0 Device Display Name: Local USB Direct-Access (mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0) Adapter: vmhba38 Channel: 0 Target: 0 LUN: 0 Plugin: NMP State: active Transport: usb Adapter Identifier: usb.vmhba38 Target Identifier: usb.0:0 Adapter Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed Target Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed Maximum IO Size: 122880

Answer (score 3):

This is not the way to accomplish VM backups in VMware. Mounting USB devices in ESXi will not do what you’re expecting.

Comment: What steps do you recommend ?